# How to specify the format of input and output data in a random forest classifier using scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I have built a random forest classifier using python and scikit learn to predict the 'pages' value from a variety of size attributes, and I wanted to specify the format of the input and output data. I want to input data from a csv file, and for the output data to be  in a json file. I have attached an image of what the data may look like in a csv file:[image]

I want to use the values in the columns of 'size2','size3','size4' as input, and for it to output the value as a json file in the following format:

```
{
  seconds: #the seconds value for those size values,
  value: pages, 
  untitled: "untitled"
}
```

I believe I am having my model only output the predicted 'pages' value right now. Thank you so much for your help!
I have attached some code of my random forest classifier, thank you.

```
 X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:50].values
    y = dataset["pages"]
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, random_state = 0)
    classifier = classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
```

Comment: what have you tried, could you post that?

Comment: what is `untitled`? also you say you are only outputting the "predicated pages", can you share that code?

Comment: @AO untitled is just the row number. I am having trouble feeding in the data so I do not know how to see its output format.

Comment: what is the function you need to feed the data into?

Comment: @AO I believe it is classifier.predict

Comment: what do you get if you `print(X_test)` that is what you are currently passing

Comment: @AO A 2d list with the testing data.

Comment: can you edit your post with that data?